# UPDATE Trigger returning both updated and previous value

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, triggers

I am trying to create a trigger that will insert a record from a table into a another table whenever a record is updated.

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[trg_tblContent_backup_update] 
   ON [dbo].[tblContent]
   FOR UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

     INSERT INTO tblContentUpdateBackup 
     (
        ContentID,
        revision,
        CountryID,
        QualificationID,
        ContentTitle,
        CourseID,
        ContentOrder,
        ContentStatus,
        ContentTypeID,
        Content,
        GenericPageID,
        GenericDisplay,
        altLanguage,
        locationID,
        languageID,
        defaultLanguage,
        courseGenericID,
        moduleID,
        ThemePageID,
        contentRelateID,
        alantestID,
        ContentBackup,
        LastModified,
        ProgrammeID,
        temp_contentRelateID
     
     )
     SELECT 
     
        ContentID,
        revision,
        CountryID,
        QualificationID,
        ContentTitle,
        CourseID,
        ContentOrder,
        ContentStatus,
        ContentTypeID,
        Content,
        GenericPageID,
        GenericDisplay,
        altLanguage,
        locationID,
        languageID,
        defaultLanguage,
        courseGenericID,
        moduleID,
        ThemePageID,
        contentRelateID,
        alantestID,
        ContentBackup,
        CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
        ProgrammeID,
        temp_contentRelateID
     
     
     FROM INSERTED
    -- Insert statements for trigger here

END
GO
```

The trigger above that I have built inserts both the previous and updated records from tblContent into tblContentUpdateBackup, however I only want the previous record.

I'm nearly there, any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: The above would only `INSERT` the details of the rows as they were prior to the `UPDATE` as you are only taking data from the `deleted` pseudo table.

Comment: You should change `FROM DELETED` to `FROM INSERTED` and then you will be fine

Comment: The code you show us cannot insert the new values as you claim, either you mistyped something or you are not showing us your actual code

Comment: Thanks @GuidoG, I have tried changing FROM DELETED to FROM INSERTED, however I then get two records of the new value inserted into my table. I don't understand why I'm getting two records using either approach.

Comment: @GuidoG, here's the complete trigger, I simplified it above...

Comment: By *previous* you mean the row before it was updated? You had it right originally then, you want to use *Deleted*. However if you are trying to capture rows as they were before being updated, why not use the built-in *system versioning*?

Comment: The latest version, @Boomfelled , would `INSERT` a single copy of the *new* row into the table `tblContent`. Maybe you have 2 triggers. Maybe your procedure you are calling is also `INSERT`ing data into the table. Maybe you're using an `OUTPUT` clause in your batch and *then* duplicating the data. We don't know, but the above isn't doing it.

Answer (score 1):

The above didn't work for me, but adding WHERE concatenation of the old != a concatenation of the new stopped the current value from writing to a history table (using insert and deleted tables). I too experienced the after update trigger writing the old and the new to history. This only happened with the app, not when testing CRUD operations in SQL SERVER.

Answer (score 0):

A freelance developer who works for us came up with the following solution, which seems to do the job:

Hi @alancoleman

So I've spent a couple of hours on this since we chatted and after various tests and reading up the only thing I've find that looks like its working is to use TRIGGER_NESTLEVEL() condition ( found something on it here https://clivesyabb.com/2014/08/06/avoiding-recursive-triggers-in-sql-vs-avoiding-nested-execution/ )

When I was testing I could see that the trigger was being called twice ( for reasons I haven't worked out ) so by using

IF (TRIGGER_NESTLEVEL()) = 1

before we do any inserting on the backup table we can make sure that it hasn't been triggered before.

I've updated the trg_tblContent_backup_update trigger if you want to take a look - seemed to be working when I tested!